# Matlab Gaussian elimination program

Tags: matlab

I am looking for a program in Matlab that takes in the number n, after that uses Matlab's function for gauss to solve the system Ax=b. Here A is nxn matrix with random numbers ranging from 0 to 1. And b is nx1 vector with random numbers ranging from 0 to 1.

I've come a bit, but I need help with some things.

First off how do I range the numbers strictly between 0 to 1 in the A and b?

Second question, how do I find the time it takes for the computer to solve Ax=b.

And also write out the biggest n where the computer solves the system under 1 minute.

Third question. How do I modify the code  so it gives me the mean of solving 20 different systems?

```
function x = GaussElim(A,b)
n = size(A,1);
for k = 1:n-1
    pivot = A(k,k);
    for j = k+1:n
        factor = A(j,k)/pivot;
        A(j,k:n) = A(j,k:n) - factor*A(k,k:n);
        b(j) = b(j) - factor*b(k);
    end
end
x = zeros(n,1);
for k = n:-1:1
    x(k) = (b(k) - A(k,k+1:n)*x(k+1:n)) / A(k,k);
end
```

Comment: First question, look at the `rand` function (type `help rand` for information). Second question, use `tic`/`toc` or `timeit` for timing (again, type `help tic`, and `help timeit`. Third question, I'd imagine you'd use a `for` loop (you know what to do now...!).

Comment: When i try to run my program, "which i havn't since i wrote the code i get "not enough arguments in line 2" And also. rand should be put on k right? as k stands for the elements in my matrix and vector?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: A.Donda, i had huge problems just puttin in the code properly, i can't do what ur asking for. Could anyone help me here?  Please?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help